# TFS 2013 Web Access burndown chart not showing any data

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Installed a new TFS 2013 instance with SSRS. Created an iteration, multiple sprints, backlog stories, assigned stories to the sprints, created tasks for each of the stories and updated the tasks with estimated effort, actual hours spent and set state to the tasks and stories accordingly. Closed some of the tasks & stories while others are active, in progress etc.

1. The team project is using MSF Agile process template. While I'm able to view the burn down, burn rate reports in SSRS, the burn down chart in TFS Web Access does not show any data. It is simply empty. I tried both in Chrome and IE, it is empty. (The SSRS reports doesn't show any data in Chrome is a different issue, they work fine with IE). What am I missing?
2. Also I've not installed SharePoint. What do I get if I install SharePoint. MSDN mentions two reports with SharePoint standard edition and five reports with Enterprise edition. Is that all comes when SharePoint is enabled? Does anyone see additional benefits. I really feel this is way complicated than it is supposed to be. TFS, SSRS, SSAS, SharePoint, Visual Studio, Team Explorer, Power Tools etc.. - too many tools and finally the reports are fragmented.
3. I'm running a TFS 2008 instance with several team projects. To start with, I want to move work items of one team project in TFS 2008 to the new TFS 2013 instance. What is the easiest way to do?

Appreciate any information on the above.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here. You'll be more likely to get good answers by posting multiple questions, one for each specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Have you set dates on your sprints on the iteration paths? I'm sure that Web Access uses this information for the burn-down chart, whereas the SSRS reports use dates in the data warehouse.
2. You can always add sharepoint later, but you'll then have to configure the sharepoint server with a special TFS sharepoint extension, and do some configuration using the TFS Configuration Manager and lastly create new sharepoint sites for all team projects and configure each team project to point to the sharepoint sites. In my opinion its not worth it. We used to have sharepoint in the 2005/2008 versions, but after a migration upgrade we simply stopped using sharepoint with TFS.
3. The easy way is to use export to excel and then import open a similar list in excel using the tfs 2013 connection and then simply copy paste from one list to another and finally publish. For full Work Item history you could look at the TFS integration platform tool found on codeplex, but beware, it can be a complicated migration process depending on process template customizations.